# Does documentation exist for the GCC built-in functions for x86 instructions?

Tags: gcc, x86, sse, intrinsics, avx

I'm referencing the GCC Intel intrinsics webpage: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html
(Not the standard [Intel intrinsics](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html) API (`<immintrin.h>`) that GCC  implement with these builtins.)

Some of these function names are cryptic. Does there exist documentation for what each function does?

For example, what do these following functions do?

```
v8sf __builtin_ia32_maskloadps256 (pcv8sf,v8sf)
void __builtin_ia32_maskstorepd (pv2df,v2df,v2df)
void __builtin_ia32_maskstorepd256 (pv4df,v4df,v4df)
void __builtin_ia32_maskstoreps (pv4sf,v4sf,v4sf)
void __builtin_ia32_maskstoreps256 (pv8sf,v8sf,v8sf)
v4df __builtin_ia32_maxpd256 (v4df,v4df)
v8sf __builtin_ia32_maxps256 (v8sf,v8sf)
v4df __builtin_ia32_minpd256 (v4df,v4df)
v8sf __builtin_ia32_minps256 (v8sf,v8sf)
v4df __builtin_ia32_movddup256 (v4df)
int __builtin_ia32_movmskpd256 (v4df)
int __builtin_ia32_movmskps256 (v8sf)
v8sf __builtin_ia32_movshdup256 (v8sf)
v8sf __builtin_ia32_movsldup256 (v8sf)
v4df __builtin_ia32_mulpd256 (v4df,v4df)
v8sf __builtin_ia32_mulps256 (v8sf,v8sf)
v4df __builtin_ia32_orpd256 (v4df,v4df)
v8sf __builtin_ia32_orps256 (v8sf,v8sf)
v2df __builtin_ia32_pd_pd256 (v4df)
v4df __builtin_ia32_pd256_pd (v2df)
v4sf __builtin_ia32_ps_ps256 (v8sf)
v8sf __builtin_ia32_ps256_ps (v4sf)
```

Comment: I don't think there is formal documentation besides the source code.  In many cases the name matches the standard mnemonic for an instruction, e.g. [`mulpd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mulpd), so you presume that the builtin emits the corresponding instruction, and can refer to the instruction set reference for the precise behavior.

Comment: Indeed, that's just what the documentation says: "All of them generate the machine instruction that is part of the name."  In a few cases, there isn't really an instruction as part of the name, e.g. `pd_pd256`.  I might guess that these are typecast intrinsics that don't actually emit any instruction, but that's just a guess.